React form not including checked checkbox values on submit
I created a new NextJS and Vite react project with the npx create-next-app@latest and npm create vite@latest respectively. I created the following simple component containing a form with checkbox input values (source code for each one slightly different depending on whether I was testing it with NextJS or vanilla React, but the examples below are more or less the source code I had):
"use client";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(new FormData(e.currentTarget), null, 4));
      }

      }>
          <label htmlFor="val1">Value 1</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val1"
              id="val1"
              value="VALUE1"
          />
          <label htmlFor="val2">Value 2</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val2"
              id="val2"
              value="VALUE2"
          />
          <label htmlFor="val3">Value 3</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val3"
              id="val3"
              value="VALUE3"
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

I then tried giving each checkbox input value its own state via:
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [val1Checked, setVal1Checked] = useState(false);
  const [val2Checked, setVal2Checked] = useState(false);
  const [val3Checked, setVal3Checked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(new FormData(e.currentTarget), null, 4));
      }

      }>
          <label htmlFor="val1">Value 1</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val1"
              id="val1"
              value="VALUE1"
              onChange={(e) => setVal1Checked(e.currentTarget.checked)}
              checked={val1Checked}
          />
          <label htmlFor="val2">Value 2</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val2"
              id="val2"
              value="VALUE2"
              onChange={(e) => setVal2Checked(e.currentTarget.checked)}
              checked={val2Checked}
          />
          <label htmlFor="val3">Value 3</label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="val3"
              id="val3"
              value="VALUE3"
              onChange={(e) => setVal3Checked(e.currentTarget.checked)}
              checked={val3Checked}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

Checked checkbox values don't appear to be included in the submitted form. An empty object, {}, is displayed in the console each time the submit button is clicked.
I imagine I either made some simple mistake or have a misunderstanding of how form submissions and/or checkbox states work or something along those lines. I can't seem to find any documentation on this nor anyone else experiencing this problem exactly. Any info or link to any info would be greatly appreciated.

what exactly does the form submit?  what is your console.log on submit showing?

Oh ya, sorry, shoulda included that in the example, I'll add it to my originally posted question, but it's showing an empty object. {}

That would be because you cannot JSON stringify a FormData instance. Why are you doing that?

I was doing that just to see what it contains, the FormData doesn't contain any of its own properties? Regardless, JSON.stringify(formData.entries()) still returns an empty object {}. Shouldn't that at least reflect the checked checkboxes?

Again, that's not going to work. Try the suggestions in this answer if you want to log something. Otherwise I'd recommend using your debugger

@Phil Thanks for the info and link! I'm guessing you suggested associating my post with that other question and I accepted it. If you want to (and still can) post an answer to the question I'll upvote it and mark it as the answer. But because I accepted it being associated with the other question it may have closed off being able to answer, I'm not sure.
